# Is it possible to turn OFF Java Web Start?

Tags: java-web-start

Is it possible to turn off Java Web Start? I'm trying to test if my browser can detect if javaws is on a machine.

Comment: What browser are you running?

Comment: Disable the Java Web Start plugin.

Comment: Follow these directions: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20Windows%20Media%20Player%20plugin%20with%20Firefox#w_enabling-or-disabling-the-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to test if my browser can detect if javaws is on a machine.

JWS is installed if Java 1.4.2+ is installed.  It was with that version that it became co-bundled with the JRE.  Between 1.2 (when it was introduced) and 1.4.2, it was available as a separate download.

To check that 1.4.2(+) is installed, use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html).

Comment: Not quite accurate.  Some 64 bit versions of Java did not include JavaWS until later on.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492248/why-does-java-web-start-not-work-with-64-bit-java-environments

Comment: @skiphoppy  Good point.  I forgot that.  Hopefully (crosses-fingers) the `deployJava.js` takes that into account.